# Calculate hours between 6 times in excel

Tags: excel-formula

There are 3 time In & Out in hh:mm, in B:C,D:E & F:G.
[image]
formula in H23 `=MOD(C23-B23,1)*24+MOD(E23-D23,1)*24+MOD(G23-F23,1)*24`
formula in I23 `=MOD(D23-C23,1)*C23+MOD(F23-E23,1)*24`

Problem is if i keep the time nil without any data for IN or OUT the result is not specific.

Comment: The result in H23 & I24 is right. As the requisite data is complete

Comment: What is this table describing ? Why is it ok that it's possible to come in and never leave like on rows 22 and 24 ?

Comment: What is the expected result when there's missing data?

Comment: The data is to be updated in real time. So after the end of the shift the data will be completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula was more or less ok, it just didn't include condition to ignore the incomplete information. The condition is simple, it makes part of the formula work only in case that both In and Out informations are filled.
Here's my formula for Prod Hrs:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)),NOT(ISBLANK(B2))),(C2-B2)*24,0)+IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(E2)),NOT(ISBLANK(D2))),(E2-D2)*24,0)+IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(G2)),NOT(ISBLANK(F2))),(G2-F2)*24,0)
```

And here's one for non-Prod Hrs:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D2)),NOT(ISBLANK(C2))),(D2-C2)*24,0)+IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(F2)),NOT(ISBLANK(E2))),(F2-E2)*24,0)
```

Comment: I also want to minus 1 hr from the "non-Prod hrs" result, but the following formula gives negative value for "0.0" data.
`=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D2)),NOT(ISBLANK(C2))),(D2-C2)*24,0)+IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(F2)),NOT(ISBLANK(E2))),(F2-E2)*24,0)-1`

Comment: You'll need extra condition for that, there are definitely shorter ways to write that but the first one that comes to mind is `IF(the formula that you wrote < 0,0,the formula that you wrote)`

Answer (score 0):

This worked! `=MAX(0,IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D24)),NOT(ISBLANK(C24))),(D24-C24)*24,0)+IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(F24)),NOT(ISBLANK(E24))),(F24-E24)*24,0)-1)`